# 'less to remember' or 'less remember'

Tags: prepositions

> **Incorrect:** The experiences of the captives held for years in dark, ramped isolation cells beneath the Lon Da camp was so monotonous and uneventful many ex-prisoners are not able to imagine, **even less to remember**, what captivity was like.
>
> **Correct:** The experiences of the captives held for years in dark, cramped isolation cells beneath the Lon Da camp were so monotonous  that many ex-prisoners cannot imagine, **even less remember**, what  captivity was like.

The above-mentioned question is from GMAT. This question is based on subject-verb related. But my question is related to preposition, that is,

1. Why is the preposition '**to**' removed? Even in [nGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=less%20to%20remember%2Cless%20remember&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cless%20to%20remember%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cless%20remember%3B%2Cc0), 'less remember' is used more.

Comment: What do you personally think is the reason it was removed?

Answer (score 2):

These examples both involve parallel structures. If we expand the parallel sentences, it becomes clear what the differences are.

> many ex-prisoners are not **able** to imagine what captivity was like
>   many ex-prisoners are not **able** to [..] remember what captivity was like
>
> many ex-prisoners **cannot** imagine what captivity was like
>   many ex-prisoners **cannot** [..] remember what captivity was like

In the first pair of sentences, the syntax is governed by **able**, which requires the infinitive-marker **to**, and in the second pair of sentences by **can**, which does not require **to**.

Comment: +1, but a nit to pick:  The full infinitives are alternate *modifiers* of the **adjective** "able".  The bare infinitives create alternate *arguments* of the auxiliary verb "can".  The word "able" is not a verb, auxiliary or otherwise, which helps to explain why it doesn't license bare infinitive arguments.  It doesn't license arguments at all.

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan: the requirement for an infinitive marker is an important topic, but I feel that the main issue in this question is paralleling. I have re-worded the final paragraph of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, I would say that you don't 'to remember' things, You 'remember' things. I.e., the verb is remember.

Rearrange the sentence:
The captives were so traumatised that they could neither imagine nor ***remember*** what captivity was like.

You wouldn't write: The captives were so traumatised that they could neither imagine nor ***to remember*** what captivity was like.

Comment: ... however you are "able **to** remember things", and that's the wording of the first version of the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

*Can* is a modal verb.  Adverbs can appear after *can* and then what must follow is another verb word.  *To* never goes in front of that second verb word.

> I can walk to the park.
>
> I can to walk to the park (wrong).